# How do museums keep Foucault’s pendulum going constantly?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, dissipation

How exactly do they keep the pendulum going with out affecting the direction it travels?
As much detail as possible please.

Comment: I am immediately struck by an image of a person gloryifying in the title "Chief Swinger of Pendulums" with a magnificent uniform to match.  Alas (probably) not the case, but I can dream. :-)

Comment: When I visited the Patheon of Paris, an employee did the job about once each half an hour, paying attention to repeat the last swing plane. The inertia was enough to allow all that time of free oscillations.

Comment: In my physics department we use a ring shaped magnet system that has a slot cut around the inner diameter, a circuit hooked up to two crossed lasers is set to activate the magnet after the wire crosses the two lasers. A metal cuff on the pendulum was gently pulled into the slot after which the circuit deactivated, thus restoring that very little loss to friction.

Answer (score 3):

One way this can be done is by parametric excitation: if you raise and lower the pivot point slightly at twice the natural frequency of the pendulum, such that it is highest when the bob is at the bottom and lowest when the bob is at either end of its swing, it puts energy into the oscillation. Since the imposed motion is purely vertical, it doesn’t alter the azimuthal orientation of the oscillation.

Answer (score 2):

Another method often used by museums is by having iron collars wrapped around the cable close to the pivot point at the top.

There will be a torus-shaped electromagnet built into the ceiling, and the cable with the iron collars swings back and forth inside this torus. Just before the pendulum reaches its maximum height, the electromagnet is given a short-lived electrical pulse which creates a magnetic field producing a force on the collar, cable and bob.

Because the pulse is extremely short-lived, and the force (in the direction of the cable) generated is of relatively small magnitude, the overall motion of the pendulum is not disrupted.

Comment: The pendulum that I had occasion to work with had a sensor in the floor, beneath the center of swing. Its function was to insure that the driving magnet (at the top) stayed in phase with the swing of the pendulum.